# Sampling from Wishart distributions with scalar degrees of freedom $(\upsilon>p-1)$

Tags: r, python, wishart-distribution

Let $\upsilon$ be the degrees of freedom of a Wishart distribution and $p$ the dimensions of its scale matrix.

If the degrees of freedom is a **scalar**, then its range is:

$$
\upsilon > p−1
$$
and if it is an **integer**:
$$
\upsilon \geq p
$$

Is there a library or some code that works for the scalar case?

**Libraries I have checked on**:

**R**. Neither of these packages work:

```
library(bayesm)
library(stats)
library(MCMCpack)

bayesm::rwishart(2.5, diag(3))
stats::rWishart(1, 2.5, diag(3))
MCMCpack::rwish(2.5, diag(3))
```

**Python**:

- [PyMC](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/master/pymc/distributions.py) (see `rwish` function)
- [SciPy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py) (see `rwishart` function)

**Matlab**:

- This is a [python version of the Matlab implementation](http://www.mit.edu/~mattjj/released-code/hsmm/stats_util.py) (I think) which accepts this case but that can draw singular matrices.

I tried, for instance, to change scipy function so that it accepts $dof>p-1$ but then it generates non positive-semidefinite matrices.

Comment: have you tried `bayesm::rwishart` ? http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/bayesm/docs/rwishart

Comment: Nope, thanks! See my edit, though. Are these guys generating singular matrices?

Comment: Your comment answers the question strictly speaking, so feel free to make it an answer :). I think I should open a different question on how to deal with singular matrices...

Comment: I don't know whether it is correct, I have never studied this question. Have you seen this warning in the help : *This routine is a utility routine that does not check the input arguments for proper dimensions and type.*

Comment: Yes, I've read it, this is why I'm assuming it is exactly equivalent to removing the checks in scipy or to the python/Matlab code I linked.

Comment: You master the question better than me. Feel free to post an answer to yourself.